# Regex not working if the regex string is stored in a separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a regex which validates the password provided by use in a form, the password must be 6 characters long, 1upper case, 1 lower case, 1 numerical and 1 special character.
Below is the react component for the form:

```
import React from "react";
import { passwordRegex } from "./Constants";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: null,
      password: null,
      disableSubmitButton: true
    };
  }

  formData = {
    email: "",
    password: ""
  };

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    nextState.disableSubmitButton = !(nextState.email && nextState.password);
  }

  initializeFormData = () => {
    this.formData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };
  };

  verifyFormData = () => {
    if (!passwordRegex.test(this.formData.password)) {
      console.error("invalid password");
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };

  submitForm = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const ifFromValid = this.verifyFormData();
    console.log(ifFromValid);
  };

  render() {
    this.initializeFormData();
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="email">Email </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={event => {
            this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
          }}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="password" name="password">
          Password
        </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          onChange={event => {
            this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
          }}
        />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"
          disabled={this.state.disableSubmitButton}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Constants.js

```
export const passwordRegex = new RegExp(
  "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$",
  "g"
);
```

**Problem**:
The form validation works fine on the first `submit`, then on further `submit` clicks, the regex behave abnormally. Sometimes it enters to the `if (!passwordRegex.test(this.formData.password))` block and sometimes doesn't enter.

**The weird thing is**: the same code works very perfectly if I create a local variable for passwrodRegex inside the `verifyFormData()` function:

```
      verifyFormData = () => {
        const passwordRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$","g");
        if (!passwordRegex.test(this.formData.password)) {
          console.error("invalid password");
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      };
```

Comment: Encoding of the file maybe? Check it.

Comment: @CodeCrusha which file?

Comment: Both. The file, which contains the regex, need to have the correct file-encoding. The other file is not that important, but should also have the same file encoding. I guess that is the problem, if not, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is, bizarrely, the 'g' flag.

Try this:

```
passwordR = new RegExp("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$","g");
console.log(passwordR.test('As!df2L$'));
console.log(passwordR.test('As!df2L$'));
```

The output will surprise you. It surprised me, anyway. (Spoiler, it's `true false`)

Now have a look at this:
[JavaScript RegExp cant use twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084926/javascript-regexp-cant-use-twice)

The headline is "RegExp instances have state when you use the `g` flag".

Finally, see if your code works as expected if you remove the `g` flag.

I've also found this, which has similar information: [Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results)

Comment: great. That worked like charm. BTW it's little weird to me that regex also have state, since I am from Java background

Comment: I think it's weird to a lot of people, whether from a Java background or not. But the js spec does hide some surprises.